# How to define two keys (PK and AK) in Microsoft Visio 2010?

Tags: primary-key, relationship, visio

I'm using Microsoft Visio 2010 and I'm trying to draw my relational database model. For the Moment I have two tables: table1 with only one column "uid" (Primary key) and table2 with three columns "id" (Primary key), "uid" and "uorder". The last two columns combined form the alternate key. The relationship between these two tables is a foreign key from table2.uid to table1.uid.

How can I form the PK AND the alternate key in Visio? And how can I connect These two tables in Visio so they Show a 1 (table1) : n (table2) relationship?

Kind regards
Nadja